# Ошибка Cannot create an instance of class space.rodionov.architecturedriller.NoteViewModel. Ищу решение

Tags: java, android, mvvm, repository, viewmodel

Приложение выдает ошибку:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance
> of class space.rodionov.architecturedriller.NoteViewModel

с указанием на строку:

```
noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
```

из `MainActivity`

Так же высвечивается ошибка

> java.lang.Class<space.rodionov.architecturedriller.NoteViewModel> has no zero argument constructor"

В чем может быть ошибка?

Код из MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NoteViewModel noteViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
    noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Note> notes) {
            //update RecyclerView
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Код из NoteViewModel:

```
public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private NoteRepository repository;
private LiveData<List<Note>> allNotes;

public NoteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    repository = new NoteRepository(application);
    allNotes = repository.getAllNotes();
}

public void insert(Note note) {
    repository.insert(note);
}

public void update(Note note) {
    repository.insert(note);
}

public void delete(Note note) {
    repository.insert(note);
}

public void deleteAllNotes() {
    repository.deleteAllNotes();
}

public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
    return allNotes;
}
}
```

Код из NoteRepository:

```
public class NoteRepository {
private NoteDao noteDao;
private LiveData<List<Note>> allNotes;

public NoteRepository(Application application) {
    NoteDatabase database = NoteDatabase.getInstance(application);
    noteDao = database.noteDao();
    allNotes = noteDao.getAllNotes();
}

public void insert(Note note) {
    new InsertNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
}

public void update(Note note) {
    new UpdateNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
}

public void delete(Note note) {
    new DeleteNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
}

public void deleteAllNotes() {
    new DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask(noteDao).execute();
}

public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
    return allNotes;
}

private static class InsertNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> {
    private NoteDao noteDao;

    private InsertNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao) {
        this.noteDao = noteDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {
        noteDao.insert(notes[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private static class UpdateNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> { ... //и так далее, 
//весь код не буду вставлять
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, проблема была во ViewMidelProvider в MainActivity.

Поменял строку на:

```
noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(NoteViewModel.class);
```

и все заработало.